# Any pointers to fix the Unix millennium bug or Y2k38 problem?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I've been reviewing the year 2038 problem (Unix Millennium Bug).

I read the [article about this on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), where I read about a solution for this problem.

Now I would like to change the `time_t` data type to an unsigned 32bit integer, which will allow me to be alive until 2106. I have Linux kernel 2.6.23 with RTPatch on PowerPC.

Is there any patch available that would allow me to change the `time_t` data type to an unsigned 32bit integer for PowerPC? Or any patch available to resolve this bug?

Comment: more of a serverfault question?

Comment: *Not* a serverfault question.

Comment: Are you in cryostasis until 2106? You're stayin' alive, stayin' alive. Feel the city breakin' And ev'rybody shakin' And we're stayin' alive, stayin' alive.... that's in the year 2106... (sorry could not resist!)

Answer (score 1):

`time_t` is actually defined in your `libc` implementation, and not the kernel itself.

The kernel provides various mechanisms that provide the current time (in the form of system calls), many of which already support over 32-bits of precision. The problem is actually your `libc` implementation (`glibc` on most desktop Linux distributions), which, after fetching the time from the kernel, returns it back to your application in the form of a 32-bit signed integer data type.

While one could theoretically change the definition of `time_t` in your `libc` implementation, in practice it would be fairly complicated: such a change would change the ABI of `libc`, in turn requiring that every application using `libc` to also be recompiled from sources.

The easiest solution instead is to upgrade your system to a 64-bit distribution, where `time_t` is already defined to be a 64-bit data type, avoiding the problem altogether.

Comment: So what's the solution for an embedded Linux 32-bit system that *will* still be in use after 2038? Or am I out of luck?

Comment: @IanGoldby There are now some solutions in Linux 5.6 https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/30/linux_5_6_2038/

Answer (score 0):

About the suggested 64-bit distribution suggested here, may I note all the issues with implementing that.  There are many 32-bit NONPAE computers in the embedded industry. Replacing these with 64-bit computers is going to be a LARGE problem.  Everyone is used to desktop's that get replaced/upgraded frequently.  All Linux O.S. suppliers need to get serious about providing a different option.  It's not like a 32-bit computer is flawed or useless or will wear out in 16 years. It doesn't take a 64 bit computer to monitor analog input , control equipment, and report alarms.

Comment: There some options in Linux 5.6. Of course, the system.will have to be reinstalled and software recompiled. But that is unavoidable.